# Ad hoc OTA deployment working on all ipads except iPad 3 with IOS 6

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, ipa, ipad-3

I am running into a weird issue for my Company. I have setup a build for my ipad app that is built with an AD hoc profile. I followed all the directions on how to set this up and is working correctly with the provision profile and the app for 5 other ipads. What i have noticed is that for some reason its not working on iPad 3 with IOS6. Here is the error i get in the console when trying:

```
Oct 31 12:00:56 Scotts-iPad SpringBoard[66] <Warning>: could not save thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null) path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/com.localbix.online.ipad-9885BA22-13CA-4388-96A0-08EDCABF459E'
Oct 31 12:00:56 Scotts-iPad SpringBoard[66] <Warning>: could not save thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null) path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/com.localbix.online.ipad-5C37022E-5875-4C48-A135-03ADD4AA75B8'
Oct 31 12:00:56 Scotts-iPad installd[30] <Error>: 0x343000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/8020495531107338408/6723207522652074632" requested by itunesstored
Oct 31 12:00:56 Scotts-iPad installd[30] <Error>: 0x343000 extract_package: Could not extract archive
Oct 31 12:00:56 Scotts-iPad installd[30] <Error>: 0x343000 stage_package: Could not extract /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/8020495531107338408/6723207522652074632 to /var/tmp/install_staging.oIwDCd/foo_extracted
Oct 31 12:00:56 Scotts-iPad installd[30] <Error>: 0x343000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Could not stage the package
Oct 31 12:00:56 Scotts-iPad itunesstored[64] <Error>: 0x1c65000 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Oct 31 12:00:56 Scotts-iPad installd[30] <Error>: 0x343000 handle_install: API failed
Oct 31 12:01:05 Scotts-iPad profiled[4231] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Idled.
Oct 31 12:01:05 Scotts-iPad profiled[4231] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.
```

The cert does have those ipad UUID's listed so its not that issue. I have ran out of ideas on what could be the issue. Any ideas? I have talked to a few others and said they have noticed the issue on the latest ipads also but have no idea. Any one else running into this issue?

Much Appreciated!

Comment: on which xcode did you build the app? 
me too face the issue, as i have build using xcode 4.4. for ios 6.0 we have build using xcode 4.5

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this problem? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Im doing this on the simulator. I have tried reseting the simulator but still having the same issue?

Comment: Do you have a proxy server defined on your wifi settings?

Comment: @ScootaP No. And the weird part is that is works fine on iOS 5. Just complains on iOS 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer out. It was as simple as my wifi setup on my ipad had our corporate proxy server defined. Because of this websense was blocking downloading of .ipa file. So if i took that same URL and put it on a desktop browser i could see it was getting blocked. Switching off the proxy fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, though no VPN, just a plain Wi-Fi setup.
iPhone4, iPhone5 and iPad2 all running iOS6 can install OTA with no issues.
At the same time, iPhone4S and iPad1 running iOS5 fail to install the app OTA.
Normal installation via iTunes sync works fine for all devices.
It's obviously an issue with OS version, but I have no idea where to look for next.
Is it in the build settings for the app or something related to server config (IIS in this case)...